# How to hide the Text Area in the Post Edit screen

Tags: posts, text

Is there a way to hide the text area box in my custom post edit screen? All entry is done through taxonomy check boxes and a couple custom fields. I want no entry in the text area.

As an alternative, how can I place a "Enter Nothing Here" text message within the text area?

I know this is a little bizarre, but is it possible?

Thanks -- Mike

Answer (score 5):

In your functions.php file where the custom post type is registered do you see:

```
'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail')
```

or something similar? If so remove `'editor'`